# Can I send eth to a contract through its constructor from another contract.

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

```
contract FirstContract {

    function createOtherContract() payable returns(address) {
        // this function is payable. I want to take this 
        // value and use it when creating an instance of 
        // SecondContract
    }
}

contract SecondContract {
    function SecondContract() payable { 
        // SecondContract's constructor which is also payable
    }

    function acceptEther() payable {
        // Some function which accepts ether
    }
}
```

FirstContract will be created from the js app when the user clicks a button on the website.  then I want to create an instance of the second contract and pass the ether along to the new contract.  I cant figure out how to call SecondContract's constructor from the first contract while sending ether.

Comment: You can split creating the second contract and sending Eth to it into two separate statements. Just create a separate function that has these two lines of code. As you call this function, if one the line fails, the whole transaction will be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I found the solution for this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract B {
    function B() payable {}
}

contract A {
    address child;

    function test() {
        child = (new B).value(10)(); //construct a new B with 10 wei
    }
}
```

Source: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html#how-do-i-initialize-a-contract-with-only-a-specific-amount-of-wei

Using your code it would look something like the following:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract FirstContract {

    function createOtherContract() payable returns(address) {
        return (new SecondContract).value(msg.value)();
    }
}

contract SecondContract {
    function SecondContract() payable { 
    }

    function acceptEther() payable {
        // Some function which accepts ether
    }
}
```